# How to find the first term of a geometric series, given the sum to n is $8 - 2^{3 - 2n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I study maths as a hobby.

I have come across this question:

The sum of the first n terms of a geometric series is $8 - 2^{3 - 2n}$. Find the first term of the series, its common ratio and its sum to infinity.

Now I know that the formula for a geometric series is

$S_n = \frac{a(1 - r^n)}{1 - r}$ and that

$8 - 2^{3 - 2n} = 2^3 - \frac{2^3}{2^{2n}}$ but I cannot see how that leads me to the first term.

Comment: Presumably the first term is $8-2^{3-2\times 1}$.

Comment: Following lulu's comment, you can then determine [1] the sum of the 1st two terms [2] then determine the 2nd term [3] then determine the ratio between the 2nd term and the 1st term.  Also, for your formula for $S_n$, the 2nd factor in the numerator should be $\left[1 - r^{(n+1)}\right].$

Comment: Thank you lulu. I should have seen that. I also appreciate your comment, user2661923

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put in values, starting from 1,2,3 and so on.
Since it asks for first term, use $n=1$.

Also for finding the sum to infinity, you need to use another formula:

$S$$\infty$ = $a/(1-r)$

where $a$ is the first term of the geometric progression
and $r$ is the common ratio.

Or, like @Rob Arthan mentioned, you can also calculate the sum to infinity by using :

$\lim_{n\to\infty} 8 - 2^{3-2n}$

This would be more useful as you wouldn't have to calculate the common ratio at all.

Comment: Why do you need another formula? You can just calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} 8 - 2^{3-2n}$. (That way you don't have to work out what $r$ is.)

Comment: Right, thanks .

Comment: Feel free to add that as an alternative in your answer.